# WCF Rest vs WebAPi

Tags: asp.net, .net, http, asp.net-web-api, wcf-rest

One of the difference which I read is "Unlike WCF Rest we can use full features of HTTP in Web API"

WebApi and wcf rest both uses Http only but I am not sure what do we mean by *full features of Http* here.
What are the Http features which are available in webApi but not in wcf rest.

Could somebody explain please.

Answer (score 0):

I think WebAPI is better than WCF because of some points of HTTP features:

- Support many formats: JSON, XML, Text, binary, ...
- Can customize Header and Body
- Easy to custom URL
- Simpler and faster (WCF is SOAP-based service)
- Support many HTTP Status codes
- Support multiple devices because the simple response and easy to customize for small devices like phone